# Exception in Delta table merge/upsert - Files were added to partition by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again

Tags: concurrency

Can we merge into a Databricks Delta table concurrently ?

I am getting below error while trying to do do.

"Files were added to partition by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again."

I  tried to merge into a delta table using one job and at the same time another job was also doing a merge on the same table.